# Specify the album of a recorded video in Android

Tags: android, uri, video-capture, android-contentprovider, mediastore

I am trying to record a video in Android using the MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE intent. I can record the video in the default library album, but I cannot store anywhere else. I have tried to use the intent parameter EXTRA_MEDIA_ALBUM:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_ALBUM, "My app videos");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

I have also tried to insert the video row in the MediaStore before the video itself.

```
ContentValues videoValues = new ContentValues();
videoValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, "My app video at" + System.currentTimeMillis());
videoValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.ALBUM, "My app videos");
Uri videoUri= getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, videoValues);

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

And I have also tried to modify the metadata once the video is inserted, to see if it is in a different album once I open the gallery application.

```
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent dataIntent) {
    ...
    Uri contentUri = dataIntent.getData();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.ALBUM, "My app videos");
    int result = getContentResolver().update(contentUri, values, null, null);
```

'result' is 1, so the row value is actually changed, but it is not in "My app videos" album once I open it.

I have also tried different solutions explained in the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) but with any Uri an IllegalArgumentException (Unknown URL file). I miss a handy method like   [MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#insertImage%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

How have you dealt with this problem?

Comment: is it must to use intent to record video for you? shouldnt you use MediaRecorder?

Comment: I would like to keep the video information in the MediaStore and use the native camera application, so use the MediaRecorder will be last option. It is 'almost' working with MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE, and I just need to specify a concrete album for my application. It should be a way to do it, because some applications like LiveProfile do it.

Comment: it is possible to store recorded video in SD card using MediaRecorder

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, although my code is on two parts, one that deals Photos and the other that deals Videos, the same process and scenario gives two different results, the following thread explains more!

http://www.androidquestions.org/threads/618-Intent-doesn-t-keep-video-extras-after-capturing-the-video!?p=1761#post1761

I would be thankful if this issue has any solutions!